# Can't seem to return value

Tags: java, class, object

I just edited my post to update my code... I am still getting an error message when I compile stating that "Cannot find symbol". I have never seen this error so I am not sure how to debug it, I really appreciate everyone's help!

```
public class HealthRecord {
    private int ID;  // stores ID number
    private String last; // stores last name
    private String first; //stores first name
    private double height; // stores height
    private double weight; // stores weight
    private double bmi;// i may need to create the bmi variable so that it can be stored (weight / (height*height)) *703;

    public HealthRecord( int ID, String last, String first, double height, double weight)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.last = last;
        this.first = first;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.bmi = bmi;
    }

    public int getID()    {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID)    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last)    {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public String getFirst()    {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String last) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public double getheight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public double getbmi() {
        return (weight / (height*height)) *703;
    }

    public void setbmi(double bmi) {
        this.bmi = bmi;
    }
}
```

---

### Next Class

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.File; 

public class OpenFile 
    { 
        private Scanner input; 

        public void openFile() throws Exception 
        { 
        input = new Scanner(new File("medrec.txt")); // opens the text file to be read (weight / (height*height)) *703); 


    } 

     public void readFile() 
     { 
        int ID;  // stores ID number 
        String last; // stores last name 
        String first; //stores first name 
        double height; // stores height 
        double weight; // stores weight      

        input.nextLine(); 

        while(input.hasNextLine()) 
            {                     
                ID = input.nextInt();  
                last = input.next(); 
                first = input.next(); 
                height = input.nextDouble(); 
                weight = input.nextDouble(); 

                HealthRecord healthrecord= new HealthRecord(ID,last,first,height,weight); 


                System.out.printf("%d", healthrecord.getID(), healthrecord.getBmi()); 
            } 
        } 

    public void closeFile() 
    { 
        input.close(); 
    } 


}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Where are you trying to return the value???  (Whether you make members private is up to you -- generally has on effect on the program logic.)

Comment: In the main you call non static method without any instance. This code doesn't compile. The main class should be renamed.

Comment: @MrD I am getting a cannot find symbol error now.. See the posted code above...

Comment: You should start out with a bare-bones program that reads and prints the file, then slowly add the logic to parse the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
System.out.printf("%d %d", HealthRecord.getID, HealthRecord.getBmi);
```

with

```
System.out.printf("%d %f", healthrecord.getID(), healthrecord.bmi());
```

Use the `healthrecord` instance that you created. The method `getID` requires parenthesis. Also `getBmi` doesn't exist as a method. Currently you have `bmi`.

---

*Aside:*

Currently this code doesn't compile. All methods in `openFile` are instance methods. You need to create an instance and use:

```
Openfile myOpenfile = new Openfile();
myOpenfile.openFile();
myOpenfile.readFile();
myOpenfile.closeFile();
```

Java naming conventions indicate class names start with *uppercase* letters, e.g. `Openfile`

---

Edit:

In your updated file, `getBmi` does not exist but rather `getbmi`:

```
System.out.printf("%d %f", healthrecord.getID(), healthrecord.getbmi());
                                                              ^
```

You may want to rename the method to `getBmi` to follow method naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks that is a great call! But now we get a "Illegal Format Conversion Exception" in the System.out.printf("%d", healthrecord.getID(), healthrecord.getBmi()); ... I am not sure how to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any bmi calculation in `HealthRecord` constructor or in getter method of bmi.
Even I don't see `getBmi()` method in `HealthRecord` class.

Add below method in `HealthRecord` class :

```
public double getBmi() {

    return (weight / (height*height)) *703; //check this formula if it is correct for BMI calculation or not
}
```

And next you need to use this call in main class:

```
System.out.printf("%d %d", healthrecord.getID(), healthrecord.getBmi());
```

Comment: So I added a new class Run. Still getting errors. I think it has something to do with where I am trying to calculate the BMI.

    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

class Run
    {
        public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
        {
            OpenFile data = new OpenFile();
            data.openFile();
            data.readFile();
            data.closeFile();
        }
    }

Comment: check your formula for bmi calculation and add getBmi() method in your HealthRecord class as I told above in my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I prematurely posted that comment. I just updated my code in my original post, but I am still getting an error when compiling- "Cannot find symbol" . I am not sure what this means or how to fix it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Replace this `System.out.printf("%d", healthrecord.getID(), healthrecord.getBmi());` with this `System.out.printf("%d %d", healthrecord.getID(), healthrecord.getBmi());` and try again...

Comment: I found the problem, I needed a %f to match the formatting in the calculation performed in the health record class